# Implementing vungle in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, ads, inmobi

How do i implement vungle in to corona sdk for only one scene. I followed the docs on corona site to implement vungle to my game. I implemented in only one scene of my game but it shows in every scene randomly, my question is how do i keep the vungle in only one scene.

I use also inmobi ads in game.

Here is the code i used.

I used this code in only one scene of my game.

```
 local provider = "vungle"
 local appId = "vungleTest"
 local ads = require "ads"

 local function adListener( event )
    if event.type == "adStart" and event.isError then
        -- cached video ad not available for display
    end
 end

 ads.init( provider, appId, adListener )
 local wasAdShown = ads.show( "interstitial", { isAnimated = false, isBackButtonEnabled = true } )
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but you can try tweeting to the folks at Vungle at https://twitter.com/vungle or try their support mail id: tech-support@vungle.com

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post all of your source so it's hard to tell the exact problem.  It seems to me that you need to have some logic around the variable `wasAdShown`, also you might want to make it a global variable.

I would do something like this:

```
wasAdShown = false

if wasAdShown == false then
   ads.show( "interstitial", { isAnimated = false, isBackButtonEnabled = true } )
   wasAdShown = true
else
   print "Ad Was Shown Already"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

`if (ads.isAdAvailable()) then
local adShown = ads.show("interstitial", { isAnimated = false })
end`

otherwise when ad get cached(loaded) it come to screen.